# How to compare time in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, timestamps

I have two time variables. I want to compare it in if statement in shell script.

e.g. 
`time1=HH:MM:SS` and `time2=HH:MM:SS`.

Format is `HH:MM:SS`.

```
if [it matched]
then
    echo "matched" 
else
    echo "not matched"
fi
```

Comment: What is the format of the times that you have in the variables? The same HH:MM:SS or something else?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller same like HH:MM:SS

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to compare the (contents of) two variables to a particular HH:MM:SS string, then just compare them to those strings and tie the tests together with a logical "and" (`&&`):

```
if [ "$time1" = "01:23:45" ] && [ "$time2" = "01:42:42" ]
then
  echo matched
else
  echo not matched
fi
```

Another option is to use `case`; it allows for some flexibility in matching the times, in case you don't want to match against a specific HH:MM:SS. To start with, let's tie the two times together with an implicit "and":

```
time1=01:23:45
time2=01:42:42
case "$time1,$time2" in
  (01:23:45,01:42:42) echo yes;;
esac
```

Here I stubbed in a comma, just to help you the script-reader see what's going on; it could be omitted.

Now let's say that you don't care as much about time2's `SS` portion:

```
case "$time1,$time2" in
  (01:23:45,01:42:*) echo yes;;
esac
```

Or maybe you want time2's seconds to be in a certain range:

```
case "$time1,$time2" in
  (01:23:45,01:42:4[1-3]) echo yes;;
esac
```

You can extend the examples from there.

Comment: I want to compare with <= operate . Kindly help me for this.

Comment: That’s not what you wrote originally; you said “time1=HH:...”. Perhaps you could open a new question that asks what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

If the format is the same, just compare them like any other string:

```
$ [ "$time1" = "$time2" ] && echo "match" || echo "no match"
```

Comment: I want to compare  with <= operate . Kindly help me for this

Comment: That is different from the question originally posed.  Please edit your question to ask what you actually want, and the answers will likely be modified to suit.